# Expand a dictionary column into rows with both dict keys and dict values as new column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a column which holds dictionary like shown below:
[image]

I want to expand the trans_score column. **I want each key, value of the dictionary values as 2 columns.** Something like this(example for first row):

[image]

How to do this in pandas?

Comment: it would be better to provide sample data as text `df.head(10).to_dict("list")`. looks like a simple case of `df.join(df["trans_score"].apply(pd.Series))` will do what you want

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [tour] and [mre] and in this case also: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to extract the dict keys and dict values **both as new column values** *(rather than dict keys as column indexes and dict values as column values)*, we need to extract them separately, as follows:

```
df_ts = pd.DataFrame({'City': df['trans_score'].apply(lambda x: list(x.keys())).tolist(), 
                      'Score': df['trans_score'].apply(lambda x: list(x.values())).tolist()})
```

Then, to expand each row into 2 rows and attach the email information, we can use:

```
df_out = df[['emailid_f']].join(df_ts).apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

Optionally, if you want to rename the column `emailid_f` to `emailid` and reset the index, you can use:

```
df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'emailid_f': 'emailid'}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Demo**

```
data = {'emailid_f': {0: 'email1', 1: 'email2'},
 'trans_score': {0: {'key11': 'val11', 'key12': 'val12'},
  1: {'key21': 'val21', 'key22': 'val22'}}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

  emailid_f                           trans_score
0    email1  {'key11': 'val11', 'key12': 'val12'}
1    email2  {'key21': 'val21', 'key22': 'val22'}

df_ts = pd.DataFrame({'City': df['trans_score'].apply(lambda x: x.keys()).tolist(), 
                      'Score': df['trans_score'].apply(lambda x: x.values()).tolist()})

print(df_ts)

             City           Score
0  (key11, key12)  (val11, val12)
1  (key21, key22)  (val21, val22)

df_out = df[['emailid_f']].join(df_ts).apply(pd.Series.explode)

print(df_out)

  emailid_f   City  Score
0    email1  key11  val11
0    email1  key12  val12
1    email2  key21  val21
1    email2  key22  val22

df_out = df_out.rename(columns={'emailid_f': 'emailid'}).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_out)

  emailid   City  Score
0  email1  key11  val11
1  email1  key12  val12
2  email2  key21  val21
3  email2  key22  val22
```

Comment: @ seaBean i get the following error: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

Comment: the part where you find df_ts worked fine

Comment: @Doof  Ok, let me look at it.

Comment: @Doof  In that case, could you try replacing the code of defining `df_ts` as follows: `df_ts = pd.DataFrame({'City': df['trans_score'].apply(lambda x: list(x.keys())).tolist(), 
                      'Score': df['trans_score'].apply(lambda x: list(x.values())).tolist()})`

Comment: @Doof  Edited my solution above.  Please try again.

Comment: The data size is quite a lot , it is taking time . will update once it runs

Comment: Thanks , it is a little slow but it does the job. cheers

Comment: @Doof  That's great!   As it needs to expand into multiple rows for each row.  It takes time.  Glad that it is still within acceptable time.